# Outputting image using php GD library via function call

Tags: php, zend-framework, gd

I know that I can output an image using GD by using

```
 <img src='draw.php'>
```

Where draw.php is a file containing the code to create an image.  How can I instead output the image via a function call (I am using the Zend Framework so will be using a View Helper) rather than simply pointing to a .php file in an img tag as above?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't.

at least not in a useable way - you could encode the image with base64:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." alt=""/>
```

i don't have any idea which browsers support this, though ... quick test:

- firefox: ok
- chrome: ok
- opera: ok
- ie6: fail
- ie7: fail
- safari: fail

ok, forget it.

but, you're probably trying to do something different - passing the file through ZF. i can't help you with that, but it should work roughly like this:

in your controller, set the output type to image/png (however ZF handles that) pass through your image and make sure ZF doesn't add anything to the output (like additional html and stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your View Helper create an image, write it to disk, and then output/return the img tag with the correct source attribute?

Comment: maybe it's an image that's only displayed once?

Answer (score 0):

Send appropriate headers (content type) and then use http://www.php.net/image_jpeg